# perl package inside a package

Tags: perl, perl-module

I need to create a common package which will be used by other packages, e.g:

common_1.pm has:

```
package common;
use test1;
use test2;
```

and use this common package into other package, like below:

content  of test_case1.pm:

```
package test_case1;
use common; // this should use test1 and test2
use test3;
use test4;
```

each test*.pm is again a separate Perl modules, can I write packages like above? I am new to oop in Perl, thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it can be done; examples of this sort of thing are [Modern::Perl](https://metacpan.org/pod/Modern%3a%3aPerl), [Test::Modern](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test%3a%3aModern), and [GID](https://metacpan.org/pod/GID).

I'd recommend using [Syntax::Collector](https://metacpan.org/pod/Syntax%3a%3aCollector) or [Import::Into](https://metacpan.org/pod/Import%3a%3aInto) as a tool to build such a module.

Here's an examples of how it could be done with Syntax::Collector:

```
package common;
use Syntax::Collector -collect => q{
use test1 0;
use test2 0;
};
1;
```

Or using Import::Into:

```
package common;
use Import::Into;
use test1;
use test2;
sub import {
   my $caller = shift;
   test1->import::into($caller);
   test2->import::into($caller);
}
1;
```

That said, if `test1` and `test2` are actually object-oriented modules (i.e. they are classes or roles), there's no need to import them at all, so the following will be sufficient:

```
package common;
use test1;
use test2;
1;
```